# Download a file from a share download link with wget

Tags: downloads, wget, shared-library, url

Hi for example if I want to download this file.

https://8ruce.stackstorage.com/s/G1BhgpdocnuLYQq

I first have to press download to start downloading the file. But I can't find the link of file url which I could download with wget. Giving this link to wget doesn't work directly. Also with inspect element I can't seem to find what the download link is exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The download is obfuscated, it will not work with wget - but probably with some *curl* magic.

Comment: With the firefox extension I mentioned in the answer I was able to generate a wget command for this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: https://superuser.com/a/1239026
It's an firefox plugin that captures the link with session ID etc..
and it provides a command you could paste in the console for curl or wget.

If anyone has a better suggestion please let me know.